# Jquery script - Issues with script not filling text input from select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Almost got my script running but I hit a roadblock. What I am currently trying to accomplish is filling a select list based on text input and vice versa. In my web application I have a text input which is read only and is usually dynamically populated and then transferred over to a multi select list where end users can only modify the text input from the multi select list.

Here is what I had so far: http://jsfiddle.net/akhyp/1983/

```
  $("#hidden_input").val(function(e){
    var ar = $(this).val().split(",");
    $("#selected_items option").each(function(){
        if(ar.indexOf($(this).val()) != -1)
           $(this).attr("selected","selected");
    });
  });
$('#selected_items').change(function(){
    $('#hidden_input').val($('#selected_items').val());
});
```

Now im still learning jquery but looked at the jquery API documents on events and .val seem to be the best fit for capturing my text input. However got some unexpected results where jquery removes the values that were dynamically added however it does end up properly selecting the appropriate option from my multi select list.

Im thinking the problem is maybe with my .change event of the select list where its not returning the data back to input. What I need at the moment is something like so:

-If the text input is null then ignore.
-If the text input is already filled then capture value and transfer it to the select list accordingly.
-If user select new options from the multi select list then capture new selected options and transfer them over to the text input.

I know its probably something I may have overlooked but I would appreciate any support on this.

Comment: seems to be working for me... can you give the steps to recreate the problem

Comment: it could be as simple as - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/akhyp/1984/

Comment: You got it Arun thank you very much. I think I was over complicating it for nothing. Ill give this a try with my application and see how well this works.